# An adverb describing added value

Tags: adverbs

**Quantitative** refers to measurement of quantity.

**Qualitative** refers to measurement of quality.

**????** refers to measurement of added value.

Here are my sentences. Feel free to refine my thinking...

- Performance is activity. It is measured quantitatively
  (how much).
- Results are the effects of activity. They are measured qualitatively (how well).
- Value is how results cause something else to be perceived. It is measured “valutatively”]

Comment: Wouldn't value be measured either quantitatively (e.g., in dollars) or qualitatively (e.g., in acceptability)?

Comment: I don't think so. You can have a lot (quantitative) of something and it could be of good quality (qualitative), but if no one wants it it has no value. So far, I've come up with "evaluatively" as maybe my best option https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixleSR1PnbAhWtzlkKHWV4Cj8QFggyMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefreedictionary.com%2Fevaluatively&usg=AOvVaw3W6ELHm6p1oBWkB1mqqe3u

Comment: Value is measuring either "how much" it is worth or "how well" it is perceived, is it not?

Comment: Yes, close at least. Perception causes value. But consider that I could look at a masterfully tailored dress and admit that its quality is exceptional. But I'm a man and I don't wear dresses, so its value to me is zero.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. As @ScottM says, value combines both quantity and quality. Performance can also combine both (in sports, distance jumped—quality—or how well a dive is executed—quality). And results (which are often just the measure of performance). As for a dress having no value *for you*, that means that it doesn't enhance the *quality* of your life.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "worth"?

Comment: @JasonBassford, the person who created the dress created a dress that is of high quality. It simply has no value to me. Value is an effect of perception and desire. If someone responded to this question with the first two lines from the US constitution, there would be a certain quantity of words and they words would be of good quality, but they would have no value to me need. Am I missing something still?

Comment: @ScottM - I need an adverb in a similar form to quantitatively. "Evaluatively" is still the closest I have come, but it isn't listed in all dictionaries and I'm not sure it is spot on

Comment: I still have to go back to my (and Jason's) previous statements. Value is qualitative and/or quantitative. You said yourself that it's a combination of perception (qualitative) and desire (quantitative). If the customer does not value the product/service, that's still a quantitative valuation (of zero), though it would also mean you need to rethink your demographic.

Comment: @ScottM - to be sure I understand, did you intended to write "qualitative" rather than "quantitative" in your sentence: "If the customer does not value the product/service, that's still a **quantitative** valuation (of zero)"

Comment: By your definition above, "quantitative" = "how much". In this case, how much = 0.

Comment: Though I am arguing your points, I am not dismissing them. I am trying to refine either your or my thinking, so please understand that I'm open to finding out I have a blind spot here.  Can you recognize the quality of a Stradivarius violin even if having one would have no value to you? It seems to me that external, possibly societal standards define quality but internal personal standards define value. ??

Comment: OK, I think I see where our thoughts are crossing rather than running parallel... There are 15 Stradivarius violins in a store (quantity). They are all masterfully crafted (quality). But I don't need a violin. To me they are worthless (value)

Comment: This discussion is going beyond what the comment section is for, so this will be my last post. If value is measured by "how much" something is worth (even if it's 0) or "how well" it is perceived, then you already have your answer. If not, then you need to be very specific in your definition of what you are looking for. I wish you well.

Comment: Some aspects of quality are immeasurable.

Comment: Here's some irony: Reading your comments, it seems like you would value a clunky word like _evaluatively_ more than you would a Stradivarius violin.

Comment: Your problem here is trying to come up with a single word (an adverb) instead of trying to figure out the most natural way to express your idea.

Answer (score 1):

To fulfil the specific request for an adverb for "putting a value on something":

[**Appraisingly**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appraised):

(This definition is for the transitive verb form.)

> **1** : to set a value on : to estimate the amount of · *appraise* the damage
>
> **2** : to evaluate the worth, significance, or status of; especially : to give an expert judgment of the value or merit of · *appraise* an actor's career

Example sentences include (emphasis mine in the first two):

> [1)](https://search.informit.com.au/documentSummary;dn=923892541824814;res=IELLCC) He came and kissed her through the window; stood back and grinned *appraisingly* as she got out; hugged her.
>
> [2)](http://digitalcommons.bard.edu/senproj_s2015/283/) "The act of looking *appraisingly* at a man, studying his body and asking to photograph him, is a brazen venture for a woman; for a male photographer, these acts are commonplace, even expected.”
>
> [3)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/appraisingly) She was looking hard and *appraisingly* at the rings as she spoke.

Comment: Bingo! That seems like a more accepted word than [lEvaluatively (or valuatively, which I also landed upon in my searches) while carrying the same nuance. Thank you!

Comment: Bingo! That seems like a more accepted word than Evaluatively (or valuatively, which I also landed upon in my searches) while carrying the same nuance. Thank you!
**Dictionaries**
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evaluatively
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valuative

**Scholarly Usage:**
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPt9fZ3_nbAhWqslkKHUKNATIQFghaMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjournals.sagepub.com%2Fdoi%2Fpdf%2F10.1177%2F1098214016641211&usg=AOvVaw33wkvy4UCK2dwLlpgYkjbS

Answer (score 0):

From an economic standpoint, the word you may be looking for is

> **marginal**
>
> **marginal** value - the value gained from either consuming or producing one additional unit of a good or service.